# Is a Chosson allowed to attend a funeral during his Sheva Brachos?

Tags: funeral-burial-levaya, sheva-brachos

Is a Chosson allowed to attend a non-relatives funeral during his Sheva Brachos?

I have looked around at some sources and have not been able to find anyone that talks about this specifically.

The basis of this question is that, presumably, during his Sheva Brachos is a time of Simcha, and attending the funeral would detract from it.

Comment: We can hold funerals even on Yom Tov, so why would this be worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[B'Tzel Hachachma 2:44:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1808&st=&pgnum=308) says that a Chasan may go to a funeral, however mentions that the Gesher HaChaim says a Chasan should not to the cemetery.

[Nitei Gavriel Nisuin2 page 128](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=127) says a Chasan should not hear a Hesped during the week of Sheva Brachos.

See also [Nitei Gavriel here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&st=&pgnum=126).